# CaliburnMicro: In my calculator app, I'd like one method to handle all of the "number" buttons (0-9) with each button passing a different value

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

Currently, I have one method in ShellViewmodel for each button on my [calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhkXY.png):

**Shellview:**

```
<Button x:Name="Btn1" Content="1"/>
<Button x:Name="Btn2" Content="2"/>
<Button x:Name="Btn3" Content="3"/>
```

**ShellViewmodel:**

```
private string _input = string.Empty;
public string Input
{
    get { return _input; }
    set
    {
        _input  = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Input);
    }
}

public void Btn1()
{
    Input += "1";
}
public void Btn2()
{
    Input += "2";
}
public void Btn3()
{
    Input += "3";
}
```

I realise this is a naive way to program my calculator, and a better solution is for each button to call the same method and pass a value (`Btn1` would pass a value of 1, etc.). The code below doesn't work; when I run it and click on the buttons, nothing happens. I could be making very dumb mistakes with the binding because I'm a beginner. What is the way to implement the binding of multiple buttons to one method, with each button passing its own value? Thanks.

**Shellview:**

```
<Button x:Name="Btn1" Command="{Binding NumberInput}" CommandParameter="1" Content="1"/>
<Button x:Name="Btn2" Command="{Binding NumberInput}" CommandParameter="2" Content="2"/>
<Button x:Name="Btn3" Command="{Binding NumberInput}" CommandParameter="3" Content="3"/>
```

**ShellViewmodel:**

```
private string _input = string.Empty;
public string Input
{
    get { return _input; }
    set
    {
            _display = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Display);
    }
}
public void NumberInput(string valuePassedFromButton)
{
    Input += valuePassedFromButton;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in `Command` property is supposed to be bound to an `ICommand` source property.

In Caliburn.Micro, you could use the `Message.Attach` property to bind the `Click` event to your method:

```
<Button cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action NumberInput('1')]" Content="1"/>
<Button cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action NumberInput('2')]" Content="2"/>
<Button cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action NumberInput('3')]" Content="3"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked a treat. I needed to add a namespace reference (might not be the right term) at the top of the View: `xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your XAML, It tries to binding Command which named `NumberInput`, as default WPF Command binding style, Not rely on autowiring of Caliburn. However, In your ViewModel, `NumberInput` is a name of Method, not `ICommand`.

I guess you have to assign implemented instance of `ICommand` like `RelayCommand` or `DelegateCommand` to `public ICommand NumberInput{ get; private set;}` , like non-Caliburn style.

- Example if you implemented `RelayCommand` or `DelegateCommand`:

```
...
public ICommand NumberInput{ get; private set;}
...

public ShellViewModel{
       NumberInput=new RelayCommand<string>((valuePassedFromButton)=>{Input += valuePassedFromButton;});
}
...
```